# How to show Woocommerce Product Vendors profile picture in every product related to that vendor

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I am trying to show instead of the default product image, the image of the vendor related to that product.

So the final result should display for each product, instead of the default product image, the image of the vendor that is the "owner" of that specific woocommerce product.

I have tried the following which is not strictly related to what I need:

https://weareag.co.uk/add-vendor-profile-image-to-woocommerce-product-vendors/

but I was not able to achieve what I wanted.

This goes very near to what I want to achieve but it's not the same thing, because it is showing the brand image separately:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/wc-brands/